# How to return list of items based on 2 table with different lengths with certain conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have 2 tables as such:

product table

| product_id | product | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | product a | url a |
| 24 | product b | url b |
| 25 | product c | url c |

price table

| product_id | product | last updated | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | product a | 25/03/2022 | usd2 |
| 23 | product a | 24/03/2022 | usd3 |
| 25 | product c | 25/03/202 | usd 4 |
| 24 | product b | 23/03/202 | usd 4 |

**output expected as list**: url b

output would be a list of urls from product table, where the condition is that

uniqueProductIdtoday = priceTable[priceTable['last updated']==datetime.date(datetime.now())]['product_id'].unique()

uniqueProductIdtoday right join product table on product Id and return unique product id.

So I am trying to get the url from product table that has not been updated in price table per datetime specified(take for example 25/03/2022).

What's the most efficient way? Do I turn the product_id that has been last updated into a list / dataframe before checking for the difference in product table by doing a merge?

Comment: What DB are you using? What you need as answer, sql command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
product_table = pd.DataFrame({'pid':[1,2,3], 'url':['http://a', 'http://b', 'http://c']})
price_table = pd.DataFrame({'pid':[2,1,1,1,3,2], 'last_updated': ['25/03/2022', '23/03/2022', '22/03/2022', '24/03/2022', '25/03/2022', '24/03/2022']})
ndf = price_table.sort_values('last_updated').drop_duplicates(['pid'], keep = 'last')
keys = ndf[ndf['last_updated']!='25/03/2022']['pid'].unique()
product_table[product_table['pid'].isin(keys)]['url']
```

Output:

[image]